# Is there a way to use Dapper Dot Net for mapping only, without querying?

Tags: .net, orm, dapper

I really like Dapper Dot Net's interface for mapping objects.  However, I already have a mechanism for returning recordsets.

Is there a way that I could just pass a flat recordset over to Dapper's machinery and have it map to whichever objects I specify?  In other words, I'd like it to serve as a replacement for things like ValueInjecter/Automapper.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in the existing API; however, the code is fully available if you want to do something different with it. I guess it largely depends on what you "recordsets" are; if thay are `IDataReader`, then it should just be a case of hoisting the reader code, and forgetting the parameterization/command code.

Comment: Thanks Marc,

I'll give that a go.  I suppose I was hoping for something more 'out of the box'.